# Collision and cloth modifier don't work

Tags: animation, modifiers, cloth-simulation, collision, manuel-bastioni-lab

I would like to use the **collision and the cloth modifier** to fit perfectly the shirt and the pants (created with adobe fuse) to the body of my character. I've created the character with the **manuel bastioni lab 1.6.1** without **IK and with muscles**. After having created and finalized the character,I've imported a **BVH file**. So,with the character in **rest position**,I've added a **collision modifier to the body and a cloth modifier to the pants** and I've clicked on the "play animation" button but it didn't work : the pants become shorter as long as the animation goes forward. I've attached some pics to show you...

collision modifer added to the body :

[image: 1]

collision modifier parameters :

[image: 2]

cloth modifier added :

[image: 3]

cloth modifier parameters :

[image: 4]

This is what happens :

[image: 5]

Comment: Just a quick thought.  Your pants are parented to the armature.  Are you using a "pinning" vertex group on the pants?  The armature parent will affect the pinned parts, the unpinned parts will be affected by the cloth sim.

Comment: Can you share the blend file? I suspect you may need to adjust some of the parameters of the simulation to get better accuracy, along with pinning as @risingfall mentioned.

Comment: no,I'm not using pinning vertex. you can find the blender file here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JZ_dOj_KmWPwkfOzwK7TtIbR1b5L0b6X